# How to pin one itemview in recyclerview. Always show that view on top of recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, listviewitem

I want to pin one item from recyclerView that always shows on top of recyclerview. I get data from SQLite. ex.twitter pinned comment